# How to reference class library with cshtml files to azure function

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

So I have the following projects in one solution..

- 'MyAFProject', a QueueTrigger function needs to send emails.
- .net-core project called'MyServices' that is referencing the 'RazorClassLib.RazorViewRenderer'
- .net-core project called 'RazorClassLib' that contains all the templates and a function called 'RazorViewRenderer'

In short,  MyAFProject calls MyServices, and MyServices call RazorClassLib.

The problem:
My MyAFProject calls 'MyServices' to do some tasks which involves rendering templates but it cannot find the templates. I have added the 'RazorClassLib' as a reference on MyAFProject, however, the same problem occurs.

I tried:
Adding the views folder from RazorClassLib on MyAFProject root folder which works sometimes.. but still produces error like

`azure function error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Razor' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

I have also added this on MyAFProject file

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <ItemGroup>
      <OutputFiles Include="$(OutDir)RazorClassLib.Views.*"></OutputFiles>
      <OutputFiles Include="$(OutDir)MyAFProject.deps.json"></OutputFiles>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Move SourceFiles="@(OutputFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)bin\" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"></Move>
  </Target>
```

What is the possible solution to this problem? All I need is to be able to call a method inside my azure function that does view rendering, but it gives me 'cannot find view file' errors and if it does, I still get mvc,razor,linq `does not exist in the namespace`.

Note that my service and razorclasslib is fully functioning except when I use it in my azure function. Been stucked with this problem for few days already. A little help will be much appreciated.